# How to find the right python interpreter in conda environments?

Tags: python, ubuntu, centos, cython, centos7

I am using a Conda environment which has installed Python 3.8. My system also has a python 3.7. See below:

```
$ which python3.8
/data0/congmin/miniconda/bin/python3.8
(base) [congmin@localhost ~]$ which python3.7
/usr/local/bin/python3.7
```

And both have cython installed as below:

```
]$ python3.8
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cython
>>> 
[4]+  Stopped                 python3.8
(base) [congmin@localhost ~]$ python3.7
Python 3.7.4 (default, Feb 24 2020, 16:34:54) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cython
>>>
```

However, in my conda environment (Python 3.8) when I use 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build a project, it always gives an error message:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cython': 'cython'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Why does it use Python 3.7 while executing in my Python 3.8 environment? Also, why doesn't it report cython not found? Because both 3.7 and 3.8 have cython installed. I am working on CentOS 7 but Ubuntu doesn't have this issue. On CentOS 7 I have to use 'sudo' because I have to log in as a regular user and on Ubutun I directly logged in as 'root' user and execute the command without using 'sudo'. Could this difference of using or not using sudo cause the issue on two different systems? In any case, how can I possibly solve the problem on CentOS7?  The full error message is below:

```
sudo python setup.py build_ext --inplace
Cythonizing sources
Processing token.pyx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 840, in setuptools_main
    return main(command_line = 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 858, in main
    result = compile(sources, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 780, in compile
    return compile_multiple(source, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 750, in compile_multiple
    context = options.create_context()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 597, in create_context
    self.cplus, self.language_level, options=self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 80, in __init__
    from . import Builtin, CythonScope
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/CythonScope.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .UtilityCode import CythonUtilityCode
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/UtilityCode.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .TreeFragment import parse_from_strings, StringParseContext
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/TreeFragment.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .Visitor import VisitorTransform
  File "Cython/Compiler/Visitor.py", line 12, in init Cython.Compiler.Visitor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 40, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 35, in <module>
    from token import *
  File "token.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.tokens.token
    # cython: infer_types=True
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 152, in <module>
    from . import random
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    from . import _pickle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/random/_pickle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .mtrand import RandomState
  File "_bit_generator.pxd", line 14, in init numpy.random.mtrand
  File "_bit_generator.pyx", line 255, in init numpy.random._bit_generator
AttributeError: type object 'numpy.random._bit_generator.SeedSequence' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data0/spbo/bin/cythonize.py", line 60, in process_pyx
    ["cython"] + flags + ["-o", tofile, fromfile], env=os.environ
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 323, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cython': 'cython'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data0/spbo/bin/cythonize.py", line 169, in <module>
    run(args.root)
  File "/data0/spbo/bin/cythonize.py", line 158, in run
    process(base, filename, db)
  File "/data0/spbo/bin/cythonize.py", line 124, in process
    preserve_cwd(base, process_pyx, root + ".pyx", root + ".cpp")
  File "/data0/spbo/bin/cythonize.py", line 87, in preserve_cwd
    func(*args)
  File "/data0/spbo/bin/cythonize.py", line 78, in process_pyx
    raise Exception("Cython failed")
Exception: Cython failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 199, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 187, in setup_package
    generate_cython(root, "spacy")
  File "setup.py", line 114, in generate_cython
    raise RuntimeError("Running cythonize failed")
RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed
```

Comment: Do you have an alias that points python to a different version? It could be that python points something entirely different from 3.7 or 3.8. Try 'which python'

Comment: No. 'which python' points to python3.8 in my miniconda environment.

Comment: you run `python` with `sudo` so you should check it also with `sudo` - `sudo which python`. And `import cython` you should also check with `sudo python3.8`. Admin may have different settings.

Comment: if you know full path to Python which has `cython` then you should also use `sudo /full/path/to/python3.8 ...`

Comment: @furas, I use the full path to p3.8 and now it won't look for p3.7, which is right. However, it still report this error: 'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cython'', but cython is correctly installed for python3.8, which have been verified. What's the issue? This is on CentOs, and Ubuntu doesn't have this issue.

Comment: maybe `python` or `python3` links to `python3.7` and then it may run some subprocesses with `python` so it runs it with `python3.7`.You may try to remove link to `python3.7` and set link to `python3.8`. OR maybe you should run all in virtual environment (`venv`) which will link `python` and `python3` to `python3.8`